# onFocusChange event doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, onfocuschangelistener

My question is about Android/Java.

In my main.xml I have two Views:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/mainEditText1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my MainActivity.java I set the OnFocusChangeListener:

```
    et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            et.setError("Lost the focus");
        }
    }
});
```

When I click the button, an error message should be shown, because I am leaving the EditText. But it doesn't happen so. Why? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

On click of you button clear focus from `edittext`.

Add  `<requestFocus />` to xml after your edittext.

Add `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to your Edittext.

Example XML Code:

```
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:ems="5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mainEditText1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
            <requestFocus />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                android:id="@+id/mainButton1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Add this code in your java file:

```
 e.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    e.setError("Lost the focus");
                }else{
                    b.clearFocus();
                }
            }
        });
        b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                e.clearFocus();
            }
        });
```